# Can not clear table from sqlite in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am updating the server data talble at every 5 minutes using service and i want to clear the all the data in the table and then update the new data from server so i am using this code before updating the table to clear the data:

```
public boolean deleteServerData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    if (getServerDataCount() > 0) {
        if (db.delete(TABLE_SERVER_CONTACTS, null, null) > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } else
        return true;
}
```

But when is count the rows in the table before deleting it gives me any number say "13" and after deleting it gives me zero but when i see at the table data it still there and updated data is appended in the table so table can not clearing data at all.

please suggest me if any solution is there or any mistake is done by me in the code.

Comment: the code you posted looks like it should work, your problem is probably elsewhere, e.g. when inserting data back into the table.

Comment: yes...you are right. this code was working fine but i was using arraylist to add the data and after updation i didnt clear the list so data was just appended.
how silly mistake i have made. :D
thnks for your hint zapl... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **execSQL**:

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_SERVER_CONTACTS);
```

Comment: @Rushabh Patel This answer will definitely help you.